Kubernetes cert-manager certificate issuing problem: no such host" logger="cert-manager.controller"
I'm trying to install kubernetes-dashboard with ingress-nginx and cert-manager, i'm also using NodePort as my service (as k8s self-hosted on VPS).
This is error i'm struck with:
kubectl logs cert-manager-57d855897b-ncfh9 -n cert-manager

1 sync.go:208] "propagation check failed" err="failed to perform self check GET request 'http://kube.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/n1dDA-0omTQgX1aNHLZ4u16mVv0TSP1J40ikSDuEm1M': Get "http://kube.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/n1dDA-0omTQgX1aNHLZ4u16mVv0TSP1J40ikSDuEm1M": dial tcp: lookup kube.mydomain.com on 169.254.25.10:53: no such host" logger="cert-manager.controller" resource_name="kubernetes-dashboard-1-2318444317-3591028914" resource_namespace="kubernetes-dashboard" resource_kind="Challenge" resource_version="v1" dnsName="kube.mydomain.com" type="HTTP-01"

This is my cluster issuer:
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: mymail@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx

and my ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - kube.mydomain.com
      secretName: kubernetes-dashboard
  rules:
    - host: kube.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: kubernetes-dashboard-kong-proxy
              port:
                number: 443

My services
NAMESPACE              NAME                                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
cert-manager           cert-manager                           ClusterIP   10.233.16.43    <none>        9402/TCP                     88m
cert-manager           cert-manager-cainjector                ClusterIP   10.233.30.141   <none>        9402/TCP                     88m
cert-manager           cert-manager-webhook                   ClusterIP   10.233.58.32    <none>        443/TCP,9402/TCP             88m
default                kubernetes                             ClusterIP   10.233.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                      3h39m
default                my-service                             ClusterIP   10.233.59.123   <none>        8080/TCP                     74m
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller               NodePort    10.233.50.143   <none>        80:31321/TCP,443:31732/TCP   120m
ingress-nginx          ingress-nginx-controller-admission     ClusterIP   10.233.35.145   <none>        443/TCP                      120m
kube-system            coredns                                ClusterIP   10.233.0.3      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       3h34m
kube-system            metrics-server                         ClusterIP   10.233.45.81    <none>        443/TCP                      3h33m
kubernetes-dashboard   cm-acme-http-solver-82rcx              NodePort    10.233.6.209    <none>        8089:31292/TCP               16m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-api               ClusterIP   10.233.59.78    <none>        8000/TCP                     88m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-auth              ClusterIP   10.233.11.67    <none>        8000/TCP                     88m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-kong-proxy        ClusterIP   10.233.35.187   <none>        443/TCP                      88m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.233.48.68    <none>        8000/TCP                     88m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-web               ClusterIP   10.233.9.17     <none>        8000/TCP                     88m

